# Why does Excel take so long to calculate and producing inaccurate results?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet, BO2009, that is 300k rows long. Only one column contains a formula The others are all pasted values so only one formula needs to be calculated in the entire workbook. Here is the formula: `=IFERROR(INDEX('RE2009'!H:H,MATCH('BO2009'!A2,'RE2009'!A:A,0)),1)` This formula is copied down to the bottom of the sheet, so 300k times.

RE2009 sheet has 180k rows. 'RE2009'!H:H contains decimal numbers and 'RE2009'!A:A, 'BO2009'!A:A contain ID codes--an 8 character combination of numbers and letters. Both 'RE2009'!A:A, 'BO2009'!A:A are formatted as general.

I use INDEX/MATCH all the time and while most of my spreadsheets are not 300k long, 60k-100k is typical. Right now it takes a couple minutes of my CPU devoting 99% to Excel in order to finish the calculation.

Is that normal? Is there any way to improve Excel's performance?

On top of that I am getting inaccurate results: instead of 0.3 the lookup produces an error.

As suggested, I have filtered the BO2009 sheet down to 80k rows, but still have the same issues. I decided to look at a single formula in particular: `=IFERROR(INDEX('RE2009'!H:H,MATCH('BO2009'!A108661,'RE2009'!A:A,0)),1)` to see if it worked correctly. The ID that it is looking for with the MATCH function is the 3rd entry in the lookup array, but it still isn't able to produce the correct value (0.3)

Comment: You might be able to speed it up by referencing only the rows that have data, instead of the entire column.

Comment: `match()` searches a range of cells. so basically you're running 300,000 searches.

Comment: I can appreciate the size of the calculation, but I've run into a new issue as well... The results of the formula are incorrect/incomplete.

Comment: When you want help with your incorrect/incomplete results, let us know.

Comment: Check for leading/trailing spaces in `'RE2009'!A:A` and `'BO2009'!A:A`. Also text that look like numbers masquerading as true numbers. *"The results are incorrect/incomplete"* isn't much to go on. I might be able to propose an alternate method if I knew what 'Only one column' actually was.

Comment: OK, I'll add some of those details.

Comment: `match(_,_,0)` is exact match -- so you have 300,000 linear searches. If the search range is sorted then you should be able to speed it up dramatically. See this for an excellent discussion: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/developing-faster-lookups-part-1-using-excels-functions-efficiently/

Comment: If you put `='BO2009'!A108661='RE2009'!A4` into a cell, does it return TRUE? If not, why not? I cannot see your computer screen and don't have access to your workbook.

Comment: Is one right-aligned and the other left-aligned? Text is left-aligned by default, true numbers are right-aligned by default and `"123"` does not equal `123`. Also, are you basing your observations on the displayed value? Is the underlying true value `123.12345` but you are displaying (and comparing) `123.12`?

Comment: Originally, when I compared the two cells directly, it produced FALSE. I checked the formula bars for leading/trailing spaces, saw none, and both were formatted to text... I guess the leading/trailing spaces were truly hidden because once I used TRIM, the direct comparison produce TRUE. Once I trimmed both columns, I used a double binary search and it calculated the entire worksheet in a matter of seconds! Here's the new formula: `=IF(IFERROR(INDEX('RE2009'!A:A,MATCH('BO2009'!A2,'RE2009'!A:A,1)),1)<>'BO2009'!A2,1,INDEX('RE2009'!H:H,MATCH('BO2009'!A2,'RE2009'!A:A,1)))`

Comment: Thanks again, Jeeped! I appreciate your knowledge and your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've found a satisfactory solution to your problem(s) but as a matter of curiosity, you may wish to time this against your current formula based solution to see if there is a measurable increase in speed.

```
Sub index_match_mem()
    Dim v As Long, vVALs As Variant, vTMP As Variant
    Dim dRE2009 As Object

    Debug.Print Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("RE2009")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count, 8)
                vTMP = .Cells.Value2
            End With
        End With
    End With

    Set dRE2009 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dRE2009.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    For v = LBound(vTMP, 1) To UBound(vTMP, 1)
        If Not dRE2009.exists(vTMP(v, 1)) Then _
            dRE2009.Add Key:=vTMP(v, 1), Item:=vTMP(v, 8)
    Next v

    With Worksheets("BO2009")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 2).Offset(1, 0)
                vVALs = .Cells.Value2
                For v = UBound(vVALs, 1) To LBound(vVALs, 1) Step -1
                    If dRE2009.exists(vVALs(v, 1)) Then
                        vVALs(v, 2) = dRE2009.Item(vVALs(v, 1))
                    Else
                        vVALs(v, 2) = 1
                    End If
                Next v
                .Cells = vVALs
            End With
        End With
    End With

    dRE2009.RemoveAll: Set dRE2009 = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print Timer

End Sub
```

This will produce static values in column B of the **BO2009** worksheet. The elapsed start and stop in seconds will be in the VBE's Immediate window (Ctrl+G)

Comment: Thanks for an alternative! It always good to learn multiple ways to solve a problem.